# http handler and asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a http hanlder to provide service to client. Do I need to change if adopting asp.net mvc?

Comment: A little more detail is in order, methinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is built on the top of the ASP.NET engine which supports HTTP handlers. So you can use your handler in an ASP.NET MVC application. This being said, HTTP handlers are not the common way to provide functionality in an ASP.NET MVC application. Controller actions should be used but if you have this existing handler you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to. You can continue to use your handler as is.